# Python server hangs

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

I have a problem with python 3.6 HTTPServer

When the browser is sending requests everything is fine. When I send request via PostMan the request is completed (code 200) but then the requests fail. If I ping the server again via postman all pending are completed and then they continue to fail.

This is the JS that send requests to the server

```
jQuery.post("http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']?>:8081", JSON.stringify({
    auth: "security_token",
    user_id: <?php echo $_SESSION[CLIENT_LOGGED] ?>
})
```

And this is how the server process the request

```
def do_POST(self):

    contentLen = int(self.headers['content-length'])
    postBody = self.rfile.read(contentLen)

    try:
        data = json.loads(postBody.decode('utf-8'))
    except ValueError:
        self.handeValueError()
        return 

    self.processRequest(data)

    return

def processRequest(self, data):
    if (data["auth"] == self.centralKey):
        self.processCentral(data)
    elif (data["auth"] == self.clientKey):
        self.processClient(data)
    else:
        self._set_badAuth()

def processCentral(self, inputData):
    self._set_validMethod()

    phone = standartizePhone(inputData["caller"])

    if(inputData["ringing"] == "1"):

        result = getCallerInfo(phone)

        if (len(result) == 0):
            temp = CallerData(phone, -1, 0)
            self.callerInfo[inputData["internal"]].append(temp)

        for row in result:
            if (row[2] == 0):
                temp = CallerData(phone, row[0], row[1], 1)
            else:
                temp = CallerData(phone, row[0], row[1], 1, row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5])
            self.callerInfo[inputData["internal"]].append(temp)

    elif(inputData["ringing"] == "2"):
        for el in self.callerInfo[inputData["internal"]]:
            el.c_status = 2

    elif(inputData["ringing"] == "3"):
        caller = CallerData(phone, 0, 0)
        values = [value for value in self.callerInfo[inputData["internal"]] if value != caller]
        self.callerInfo[inputData["internal"]] = values

    else:
        message = '{"success": "false"}'
        self.wfile.write(bytes(message, "utf8"))
        return False

    message = '{"success": "true"}'
    self.wfile.write(bytes(message, "utf8"))
    return True

def processClient(self, inputData):
    self._set_validMethod()
    message = "["
    internalMsg = []
    internalNums = getUserInternal(inputData["user_id"])

    for internal in internalNums:
        for caller in self.callerInfo[str(internal[0])]:
            internalMsg.append(callerInfoToJSON(caller))

    message += ", ".join(internalMsg)
    message += "]"

    self.wfile.write(bytes(message, "utf8"))
```

Note that it doesn't matter if I am sending the request as central or client via postman. In both ways it just hangs. Also no errors are logged from the python script

Note 2 Updating postman to latest version seems to fix the problem